# why the okhttp asynctask not executing

Tags: android, android-asynctask, okhttp

the first 2 logs `dddddd`  and `imageurl` is being visible in the logcat but the other logs are not showed. i am not getting error the app is opening. it seems its not entering the try{} because the log.d'Fffff' did show in the logcat. why ? I am trying to load image from url and display it in the app.

```
public class OkHttpHandler extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, byte[]> {

    private final String IMAGE_URL = "http://bit.ly/1DU2Zka";

    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

    @Override
    protected byte[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d("e", "dddddddddd");
        Log.d("e", IMAGE_URL);

        Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
        builder.url(IMAGE_URL);

        Request request = builder.build();

        try {

            Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
            Log.d("e", "dddddddddd");
            Log.d("e", "dddddddddd");
            Log.d("e", "dddddddddd");
            Log.d("e", "dddddddddd");
            Log.d("e", "dddddddddd");
            System.out.println(response);
            System.out.println(response);
            System.out.println(response);
            System.out.println(response);
            System.out.println(response);
            Log.d("e", "FFFFF");
            Log.d("e", "FFFFFFFF");
            Log.d("e", "dddddddddd");
            Log.d("e", "dddddddddd");
            Log.d("e", "dddddddddd");
            return response.body().bytes();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I am calling it such way

```
public void downloadImage() {
    OkHttpHandler handler = new OkHttpHandler();

    byte[] image = new byte[0];

    try {

        image = handler.execute().get();

        if (image != null && image.length > 0){
            Log.d("e", "dddddddddd");
            Log.d("e", "dddddddddd");
            Log.d("e", "dddddddddd");
            Log.d("e", "dddddddddd");
            Log.d("e", "dddddddddd");
            Log.isLoggable("e",image.length);
            Log.d("e", "dddddddddd");
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            txtBytes.setText("Total bytes downloaded: " + image.length);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        txtBytes.setText("Hmm sorry, something went wrong!");
    }

}
```

Comment: add `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch block and post the output

Comment: thanks for that. the error was really silly. I forget to add internet permission anyway please add your comment as an answer to accept it . it was helpful

Comment: I'll close it as dup